# UIAlertController is not Getting Dismissed in some Cases

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

In my project, a video will be processed and then after some effects, it will be played. While processing the video I want to show `Please wait...` message.

I show an alert using `UIAlertController` and after finishing the process I want to hide the alert.

If the video processed correctly, the alert will be `dismissed`, but in some cases that the process failed `dismiss` also will not work! Note that `dismiss` function will be called, but it does not work.

Also, I use [`VGPlayer`](https://github.com/VeinGuo/VGPlayer) to play the video.

```
class VGViewController: UIViewController {
    var player : VGPlayer?
    var url: URL?
    var outputVideo: URL?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showLoading()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            do {
                guard let output = try effectVideo(fileURL: url) else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.hideLoading()
                    }
                    return
                }
                outputVideo = output
            } catch let e {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.hideLoading()
                    }
                print("video error: ",e)
            }
            self.player = VGPlayer(URL: outputVideo)
            self.player?.delegate = self
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hideLoading()
                self.view.addSubview((self.player?.displayView)!)
                self.player?.backgroundMode = .proceed
                self.player?.play()
                self.player?.displayView.delegate = self
                self.player?.displayView.titleLabel.text = self.url!.lastPathComponent
                self.player?.displayView.snp.makeConstraints { [weak self] (make) in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                    make.edges.equalTo(strongSelf.view)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var alert: UIAlertController!
    private func showLoading() {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait.\nThis may take a few seconds...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func hideLoading() {
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {print("**** alert dismiss called ****")})
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious. If you substitute your request code with a delay and hide the alert inside it, does it dismiss correctly?

Comment: [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller)'s `view` hierarchy is private, so... you shouldn't add subviews to it in the first place.

Comment: try adding dispatch async->
DispatchQueue.main.async {//your code}

Comment: @RobertDresler Thanks. So what should I do? When to add subviews?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this for hiding alertview.

```
private func hideLoading() {
      for subview in alert.view.subviews {
          subview.removeFromSuperview()
      } 
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {print("**** alert dismiss called ****")})
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks. It works but now user cannot back to previous `ViewController` using navigation. `ViewController` does not respond to tap and Navigation bar will not be shown.

Comment: Would you like to show then screen design UI what happens after adding this code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an error: "Warning: Attempt to present "UIAlertController: 0x7fde1b080600" on <...> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" ?

In `viewDidLoad`, your app has not presented the ViewController.

Try executing that code in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: After adding the code in `viewDidAppear` everything works normally. Thanks.
Can you explain more, what happened?

Comment: The error says that you are trying to display a UIAlertController lower than view of ViewController.

Comment: Strange :)
I added your code and got this error.
But nevertheless, it seems that UIAlertController is lower than view of ViewController.

Comment: How can I see Controllers order (which is top and which is down)?